# Powershell Script suspends when running a cmd with start

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have a powershell script based on [This](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Display-computers-status-c8ff289d)  which displays a form with IP addresses and ping results. I've heavily modified it as I use it for switches and routers.  My modification form allows me to double click on a cell to run a cmd file to run a putty command to SSH to the machine

However what I find is that the powershell scripts suspends until I exit putty.  In attempt to resolve this I made the command in side the power shell script this

.\ssh.cmd $user $computer

The SSH.CMD file contains the following

```
start "%2" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\putty.exe" -l %1 %2
```

Yes the form still suspends until I exit putty. I have got the direct putty command working

```
. "c:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\putty.exe" -l $user $computer
```

and this does not suspend - however I'd like to know why the running of start suspends the powershell form.

Comment: If you get a change, play with https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html and see if it has the same behavior. Not sure if the `/B` switch with the start command would help or not but easy enough to test I would think (https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: Any particular reason you're reaching out from your PS script to a batch script? I don't suspect you'd have this issue if you called Putty and some parameters with the `Start-Process` cmdlet.

Comment: Legacy CMD files , as I don't want to have to rewrite them all straight away. In this case I've already got Reid of this one

Comment: Finally back from travel and yes
Start-Process .\ssh.cmd "$user $computer $password"
does not suspend - so I can run cmd/batch files if needed now 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start-Process .\ssh.cmd "$user $computer $password" does not suspend